# Nodejs script executing without waiting for Mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, callback, mongodb-query

I have the following part in a nodejs file

```
client.db('metro4').collection('Station').findOne({"Name": variabled2}, function(err, res2) {
        if(err) throw err;
        variabled2 = res2._id;
        console.log("id2 = ", res2._id);
    });

console.log("v= ",variabled2);

myFunc(variabled);
```

the `myFunc` function also has some mongodb queries.

The problem is in the order of execution.

```
v = undefined
then some of function results (which are obviously wrong)
id2 = 4
then other of functions results
```

I came from running MySQL queries inside node and there weren't these problems even in long stored procedures.

Now many answers suggested 'async and await'. So, I made `myFunc` `async` & tried this

```
(async function() {
        await recur2();
    })();
```

But as expected the result are nearly same as the program is not waiting for first query.

Also, I discovered `.then()` like `Promises` but they apparantly don't work when having callback function like I have in my query above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add full example of your asym/await function. It seems you are trying to mix Promises and callbacks, which is quite advanced technique. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.3/classes/Collection.html#findOne without callback parameter returns a Promise. You should use this syntax with async/await. Remember async/await is just syntax sugar on top of Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is using callback so it won't wait for its completion. So what you need is `await` the first query, or place `myFunc` into the callback.

place inside callback

```
let variabled2;
client.db('metro4').collection('Station').findOne({"Name": variabled2}, 
    function(err, res2) {
        if(err) throw err;
        variabled2 = res2._id;
        console.log("id2 = ", res2._id);

        myFunc(variabled);
    });
```

async/await

```
(async function() {
    let variabled2;
    const res2 = await client.db('metro4').collection('Station').findOne({"Name": variabled2})
    variabled2 = res2._id;
    console.log("id2 = ", res2._id);
    myFunc(variabled);
})()
```

I would suggest the `async/await` solution as it is cleaner.

Comment: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`. I guess the function in which query is made should also be async for this

Comment: @mr.loop Oh sorry I assumed that you are running inside a function. Yes you can simply wrap it inside an async function. Just edited the answer.

Comment: the nested callbacks work but in `(async function() { await recur2(); console.log("Hello") })();` Here, `Hello` is being consoled before the completion of recur2. Don't know why. `recur2` is a async recursive (with mongo queries) function.

Comment: Well, that should works fine and I guess it is about not awaiting inside `recur2()`, i.e. using `then` or `callback`. I cannot tell what's exactly going on as I don't know what's inside `recur2()`, but if you print something on the very first of `recur2()`, that should go before `Hello`.

Comment: Yeah I figured await was not used in recursion in that function. The probelm I am encountering is `async function recur() {if { // } else { await recur() } }` it says await only valid in async functions, but `recur` is an async function

Comment: I guess it is because it is within other context like a callback function, which also needed to be marked as `async` like `async function() {...}`/`async()=>{...}`
I would suggest you to go through some tutorials about that. And also, it is better to provide all necessary context of your code (i.e. `recur()`) in your question, or provide a playground/sandbox link.

Comment: Yes, it was within nested mongodb query function like in your answer hence not overall async. Thanks